# How to get an object property value when property name is in a variable?

Tags: javascript

I need help with a function I've created.

For example, I parse a JSON string and I want to get the value of the passed parameter from the parsed JSON.

```
function returnVal(name) {
  parsedJSON = JSON.parse('{"test": "hello"}');
  return parseJSON.name;
}
```

Comment: In your snippet you're referring to `parsedJSON.name`, but the only value in your JSON string is `parsedJSON.test`

Comment: I'll use this for data, in which more than one parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
return parsedJSON[name];
```

Comment: Thanks, it's works exactly as I want

Comment: Actually, scratch that. I was the one not reading carefully enough (missed the parameter "name"). I'll remove my comment because I most certainly do not deserver the up-vote on it.